# Argument 1 passed to Darryldecode\Cart\Cart::Darryldecode\Cart\{closure}() must be an instance of Darryldecode\Cart\CartCondition

Tags: php, laravel, cart

\Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError

Argument 1 passed to Darryldecode\Cart\Cart::Darryldecode\Cart{closure}() must be an instance of Darryldecode\Cart\CartCondition, instance of Darryldecode\Cart\ItemCollection given

C:\wamp64\www\blog\vendor\darryldecode\cart\src\Darryldecode\Cart\Cart.php:589

I just did composer dumpautoload and I am getting this error after that when I go to http://localhost/ecom/public/cart . I am using Darryldecode Cart Library. Before dumpload the cart was working fine.

Cart Create function is working fine but not index

```
public function index()
{   
    $cartSubTotal = Cart::getSubTotal();


    $condition = new \Darryldecode\Cart\CartCondition(array(
'name' => 'GST',
'type' => 'tax',
'target' => 'total',
'value' => '5%',
'attributes' => array( // attributes field is optional
'description' => 'Goods & Services Tax',
'more_data' => 'It is 5% of the total Value'
)
));

$cartTotal = Cart::getTotal();
$gst = $cartSubTotal * 0.05;
    $datas = Cart::getContent();
    //$product = Products::whereIn('id', $datas->pluck('id')->all())->get();
  return view('cart.index', compact('datas','cartSubTotal','gst','cartTotal','condition'));
}
```

Comment: can you show us some code?

Comment: you are only showing the error message, can you show us more details about the error (filename, line number)?

Comment: @Smankusors C:\wamp64\www\ecom\vendor\darryldecode\cart\src\Darryldecode\Cart\Cart.php:589

Comment: hmm the vendor... do you make any changes on vendor code? If not, you can delete this folder, and run `composer install`, see if that resolve this

Comment: @Naren did you manage to fix this?

Comment: No @mafortis I could not

Comment: It might be that your `id` column of the table is of `int` type. Please ensure that it is of textual type, like this: `$table->string('id')->index();`

Answer (score 1):

Ran into the same issue, using example code from Darryl.
CacheStorage is working fine, but switching to DatabaseStorage gave the error.

As I don't use conditions, this simple fix in DbStorage will do for me:

```
public function get($key)
{
    $cart = $this->has($key);
    if($cart)
    {
        if (str_contains($key,'conditions')) {
            return $cart->conditions; // return empty array
        }
        else {
            return new CartCollection($cart->cart_data);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return new CartCollection([]);
    }
}
```